# How do I find the position of the maximum value in a column of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the position of the maximum value in a specific column of a  numpy array.

The code to set up my array is:

```
m=np.zeros((3,4),dtype=int)

for i in range (0,3):
    m[0][i]=1;

m[1][1]=1
m[2][0]=1
m[2][1]=1
m[0][3]=2
m[2][3]=1
print(m)
```

(I know this is a silly way to set it up but this is part of a much larger program and needs to be set up in this way)

Using this code:

```
b=0
m_e_p=np.max(m[:,b])
        print(m_e_p)
```

I get the answer 1 since 1 is the maximum value in column 0, but I need its position. How do I get this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) on the `ndarray` sliced by the column of interest:

```
print(m)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1]])

np.argmax(m[:,col])
```

**Example**

```
np.argmax(m[:,3])
# 0
```